# Как загрузить json по ссылке

Tags: json

Как загрузить json по ссылке https://search.acestream.net/?method=search&api_version=1.0&api_key=test_api_key&query=discovery на свою страницу сайта и отобразить его в распарсеном виде?

Comment: опишите подробнее вопрос

Comment: Вообще JSON это формат. Может Вы хотите информацию получаемую в формате JSON со стороннего сайта распарсить и потом отобразить на сайте у себя?

Comment: нужно отобразить содержимое json у себя на сайте, делал загрузку с помощью javascript по этому примеру:  <div id="placeholder"></div> <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>; <script> $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { var output="<ul>"; for (var i in data.users) { output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + "--" + data.users[i].joined.month+"</li>"; } output+="</ul>"; document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output; });все получилось, но мне нужно загрузить json по ссылке, а не по загруженому уже на сайте json файла вида data.json

Comment: @Андрей, вы точно уверены, что вопрос-дубликат решает вашу проблему?

Comment: нет он не решил, я думаю там другой пример, мне нужно чтобы при загрузки страницы сайта, отображались json данный в распарсеном виде загружаемые по ссылке, а не по загруженому в корне сайта json файлу, (у меня только так получается загрузить file.json), а нужно http: //другой-сайт-json

Answer (score -1):

getJSON возвращает js объект data, с ним уже знаете как работать 
[в документацию >>](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```js
$.getJSON( "https://httpbin.org/get?method=search&api_version=1.0&api_key=test_api_key&query=discovery", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать, я в этом деле новичок)

Comment: обращайтесь к элементам data через точку. Например: data.total

Comment: разобрался, сделал запрос при помощи php $endpoint = 'search.acestream.net/…;; $json = file_get_contents($endpoint); $data = json_decode($json, true); print_r($data);